# flutter is not running on windows

Tags: flutter

After installing flutter and running my emulator it stops at initializing gradle on android studio and on vs code.

It outputs:

> this is taking an unexpectedly long time.

I ran flutter doctor and no issues and also [flutter doctor -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh7OU.png) and still no issues. I tried flutter upgrade but still no difference.

What is the next thing to try?

[flutter error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPD4X.png)

Comment: Did you get some kind of error? Did it just freeze?

Comment: i think the problem is  in the android sdk, did you try to run a native android project(in java or kotlin)?

Comment: Can you add some error logs?

Comment: @amol G i updated the question

Comment: @sami kanafani no i have not tried that. if it is my sdk how do i proceed

Comment: @sven it just freezes all the time

Comment: @sami kanafani no i have not tried that. if it is my sdk how do i proceed

Comment: is there any specific gradle fail error logs in android studio when you run the app? that would be more helpful than `flutter doctor` logs. still make sure following points 1.you have working internet connection 2. android sdks are available 3. if you have added any dependency in gradle make sure it is correct. Is gradle failure occuring on every project you are creating in flutter ? if not there might be some issue with your project gradle. also check Dart Analysis tab for any compile time errors.

Comment: you just need to create a normal android project and run it, and  check if it freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is just taking forever to start; You can read the thread on the issue on 
[Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15106):

To summaries: here is one of the issues: [Downloading 400mb of dependencies](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15106#issuecomment-461841994)

> Solved Initializing gradle problem
>
> The problem is that when first time we are trying to run our flutter
>   project it does not have the required flutter gradle file. The
>   required file size that gradle downloads is about 300-400MB that's why
>   it takes so much time. Following are the steps:
>
> Run your project by clicking on the 'Run' button or flutter run in the command terminal
>           Then go to the place where your .gradle file is located (usually it is in the C:\Users). In the .gradle folder there is file
>   name as wrapper in this there is dists folder. In dists folder there
>   is gradle folder which is being downloaded.
>           wait till the gradle file is being downloaded and after sometime your project would compile.
>
> its working thaaaaaanks

I am new to mobile development; Everything takes eternity.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by removing all the gradle files from

C:\Users\.gradle\wrapper\dists

Now when you run your flutter app, it will automatically download the required gradle files.

Enjoy!!!